# Evaluating and comparing a variable to key pairs of a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a dictionary that hosts diameter(in mm) and worth of euro coins:

```
CoinsDiameters = new Dictionary<float, decimal>
                {
                    {25.75F, 2.00m},
                    {24.25F, 0.50m},
                    {23.25F, 1.00m},
                    {22.25F, 0.20m},
                    {21.25F, 0.05m},
                    {19.75F, 0.10m},
                    {18.75F, 0.02m},
                    {16.25F, 0.01m}
                };
```

So for example a 50 Euro cent coin has diameter of 24.25 mm. after some image processing, I get the rough diameter of a 50 cent coin in an image that is 24.1 mm in diameter. I tried to write the code below by having in mind a +/- 0.2 mm of error, but it always returns the first value in the dictionary (the 2.00 euro coin). What can be wrong with the logic?

```
public decimal GetValueForDiameter(float diameter)
{
    foreach(var key in CoinsDiameters.Keys)
    {
        if (diameter < key + 0.2F || diameter > key - 0.2F)
        {
            return CoinsDiameters[key];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't use a debugger, did you?

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this:

```
if (Math.Abs(diameter - key) <= 0.2F)
```

Comment: @appclay Yes I noticed that right after I posted and fixed it. should be `<= 0.2F` I believe.

Comment: Hmmm this does not return anything :(

Comment: @Sean87 Great! ... You gave me a slight scare there. I thought I had my basics right :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you should replace the `||` with `&&` :)

Comment: Precisely. That logic is first checking if the diameter is less than 25.95 *or* greater than 25.55. Obviously this check is always true, and thus any input will return the first value in the dictionary.

Comment: Agreed. This logic seems to suggest that as long as the diameter is not equal to the key value (+- 0.2) that key is the one sought after. Hence the first one is chosen because it will always qualify.

Comment: I think the logic suggests that @Sean87 made a simple mistake that we've probably all made at some point.

Comment: Yeah..really my brain was hanged at that moment because  I spend so much time for image processing that this small error was like climbing everest for me!